# Set enumarated value in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to write a parser for Log4js like:

```
{   "default": "INFO",   "communication": "WARN" }
```

and I need to restrict values like: INFO and WARN.

What I have tried:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  properties:{
    type: 'string'
  }, enum: {
    ['WARN', 'INFO']
  }
}
```

Comment: A parser to do what?

Comment: To: WARN and INFO. I want to have only those as validated levels.

Comment: I think you have a few missunderstandings about how JSON Schema works. Can I suggest you read our getting started guide (in full) found at http://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html =] You may find you can work out your problems after that. Please come back and say if that's not the case.

Comment: @Relequestual The schema I have answered works good with "{   "default": "INFO",   "communication": "WARN" }" ;-) I understand how works schema.

Comment: Glad to see you found the guide useful. The schema in your question strongly suggests you are not familiar with JSON Schema, as it is not a valid JSON Schema. I'm happy to help further if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is following:

```
{
  type: "object",
    
   patternProperties: {
  ".*": {
     type: 'string',
     enum: ["ALL", "DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR", "FATAL", "OFF", "TRACE"]
  }
   }
}
```

Comment: In stead if `patternProperties`, you could use `additionalProperties, which will be applicable to all properties not defined in `properties`.